# Linked list deck of cards, only 51 cards appearing not 52

Tags: c++, linked-list

What I'm doing in this program is I'm randomly creating a linked list of 52 cards then displaying them. But when I compile all this comes out to is 51 cards and I can't seem to figure out why there is always a card missing. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
struct card
{
    int cardvalue;
    card *next;
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int i,j=0,q,tempo=0, z,temp2=0,temp3=0,x,num1,num2=0,t, count=0, label=1,face=0,suit=0, m, count2=0;

    char suits[4]={'C','D','H','S'};
    char ranks[13]={'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A'};   

    card *start=NULL,*ptr,*temp;
    int prevdrawnnum[52];
    for(x=0; x<52; x++)
    {
        prevdrawnnum[x]=0;
    }

    for(t=0; t<52; t++)
    {
        num1=rand()%52;
        if(prevdrawnnum[num1]==1){
            while(prevdrawnnum[num1]==1){
                num1=rand()%52;
            }
        }

        prevdrawnnum[num1]=1;
            ptr = new card;
        ptr->cardvalue=num1;
        ptr->next=NULL;

        if(start==NULL)
            start=ptr;
        else
        {
            temp=start;
            while(temp->next!=NULL)
                temp=temp->next;
            temp->next=ptr;
        }
        count++;
    }

    temp=start;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {   
        num2=temp->cardvalue;
        suit=num2%4;
        face=num2/4;
        cout<<label<<". "<<ranks[face]<<"-"<<suits[suit]<<endl;     //prints the shuffled decks
        label++;        

        temp=temp->next;
    }

    cout<<count<<endl;
    for(tempo=0; tempo<52; tempo++)
    {
        cout<<prevdrawnnum[tempo];
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you try to create a list of 51? Or three?

Comment: **HINT:** think about `while(temp->next!=NULL)`...

Answer (score 0):

After reading the code I found why you have 51 cards. While creating the card values in first for loop you are assigning the first node to a variable called "start". And while printing you are only traversing "temp" which does not has "start" . The reason why you have one less element in the list start is not in the list